# Error Occured When Import K8s Taints Api by go mod

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I want to use api to add(remove) taint to(from) k8s node,go code like this:

```
import (
     taints "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/taints"
)

newNode, updated, err := taints.AddOrUpdateTaint(node,taint)
newNode, removed, err := taints.RemoveTaint(node,taint)
```

but when I sync dependencies by GoLand,error occured:

> go: finding module for package k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/taints
> go: found k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/taints in k8s.io/kubernetes v1.19.0
> go: k8s.io/kubernetes@v1.19.0 requires
>     k8s.io/api@v0.0.0: reading k8s.io/api/go.mod at revision v0.0.0: unknown revision v0.0.0

`go.mod` in my project like this:

```
go 1.14

require (
    github.com/gammazero/workerpool v1.0.0
    github.com/glc v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
    github.com/golang/glog v0.0.0-20160126235308-23def4e6c14b
    github.com/mediocregopher/radix.v2 v0.0.0-20181115013041-b67df6e626f9
    github.com/robfig/cron v1.2.0
    github.com/spf13/pflag v1.0.5
    gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.3.0
    k8s.io/api v0.19.0
    k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver v0.19.0
    k8s.io/apimachinery v0.19.0
    k8s.io/client-go v0.19.0
    k8s.io/metrics v0.19.0
    sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime v0.6.2
)
```

I have found some issues about this error,but it doesn't seem to work for me.(https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/79384)
Hope someone can help,thanks~

Comment: Edit the question to add your go code and go.mod file

Comment: @Arghya Sadhu,Thank you,I have already edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [script](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/79384#issuecomment-521493597) suggested in the issue you mentioned:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -euo pipefail

VERSION=${1#"v"}
if [ -z "$VERSION" ]; then
    echo "Must specify version!"
    exit 1
fi
MODS=($(
    curl -sS https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/v${VERSION}/go.mod |
    sed -n 's|.*k8s.io/\(.*\) => ./staging/src/k8s.io/.*|k8s.io/\1|p'
))
for MOD in "${MODS[@]}"; do
    V=$(
        go mod download -json "${MOD}@kubernetes-${VERSION}" |
        sed -n 's|.*"Version": "\(.*\)".*|\1|p'
    )
    go mod edit "-replace=${MOD}=${MOD}@${V}"
done
go get "k8s.io/kubernetes@v${VERSION}"
```

Save this as `upgrade-k8s.sh` in the same directory as `go.mod` and run it as follows `sh upgrade-k8s.sh 1.19.0`. Then commit all the changes made to the `go.mod` file. Now you can remove `upgrade-k8s.sh` or keep for future upgrade of `k8s.io/kubernetes` module.

Comment: Yeah,I know that.But when building my project in a fully new enviroment,I need to execute this scipt,right?It seems to be inconvenient.

Comment: Nope, you don't need to run the script every time. Updated the answer. TLDR: you only need to run the script once to add all the replace items in `go.mod`, then you commit `go.mod` and don't need the script anymore.